# await is not a reserved word

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await

Here is my code,

```
exports.prepareMeshTerms = function(req,res) {
var input = req.body,
start = input.start,
limit = input.limit,
count = 0,
pipeData = '';
MeshTerms.find().skip(start).limit(limit).exec(function (err, data) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
    if (data) {
        (async function(){
            data.map(element => {
                var string = element.Intervention.replace("|"," "),
                payload = { json: { input: element.Intervention } };
                await execute(payload,count,pipeData,element);
            });

        })();
    }
});};
```

It says await is not  a reserved keyword.Here I kept async in the self called function but still it throws error.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: Which version on Node.js are you running?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do a sync `map` with `await` inside. Instead use `Promise.all` to create a `map` of async functions:

```
        await Promise.all(data.map(async (element) => {
            var string = element.Intervention.replace("|"," "),
            payload = { json: { input: element.Intervention } };
            await execute(payload,count,pipeData,element);
        }));
```